# Styling WMS layers in OL3

Tags: wms, sld, openlayers

I have managed to get my WMS layers working in OL3.
Now I want to style them, as they are all set as blue on the server side and I can't change that. 
I know the common answer seems to be WMS is an image and you can't style it like a vector but there are examples of people doing complicated dynamic styling with SLDs so it must be possible to use an SLD to change the layer colour - depending on the server?

I have had a look at one [example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.9.1/examples/WMSPost.html)but that is OL2.9 and for WMS.post layers and I don't know what they are.

My rough ol3 code is [here](http://www.knittedpenguin.com/wmscolour.html) so you can see where I am at

Answer (score 3):

Styling WMS layers using SLD still means images styled on the server.

Open-source WMS implementations like GeoServer and MapServer support styling WMS layers with SLD. See the SLD-related [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/ogc/sld.html) and [GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-introduction.html)  docs for example.

So one option is to create the SLD on the client and send it in the WMS `GetMap` request through the `SLD_BODY` query string param. The WMS then uses the SLD for the rendering on the image.

Using OpenLayers 3 this will look like this:

```js
var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
    url: http://url-to-wms.com,
    params: {
      // ...
      'SLD_BODY': urlEncodedSLDString
    }
  })
});
```

Note that, as opposed to OpenLayers 2, OpenLayers 3 doesn't support sending WMS `GetMap` requests using `POST`. Using `POST` allows sending SLDs of practically any size, but the implementation in OpenLayers 2 is, in my opinion, not very robust—I won't use it in production.

But do you really need to create the style definition on the client? If you just need a fixed number of style definitions you can define style definitions on the server, once for good, and refer to them by their names in WMS `GetMap` requests, through the `Style` query string param. I'd recommend using this if you don't need to define styles dynamically on the client.

Comment: Thanks that's a very good explanation. I have tried adding the 'SLD_BODY' and a link to a SLD from the SLD cookbook and nothing changes so it could be the server doesn't support sending SLDs. I am trying to use the public served files as we don't have a geoserver at work.

Comment: Yes, the WMS needs to support SLD for the `SLD_BODY` and `SLD` params to work as expected.