# Passing SLD as variable in parameter in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, openlayers

I have a wms layer and I want to pass the sld variable in a parameter. I refer to

[Styling WMS layers in OL3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127948/styling-wms-layers-in-ol3) as well but cannot solve.

The fiddle is

http://jsfiddle.net/shumanbaral/x6qwyuvk/1/.

Here,

```
tile_wms.getSource().updateParams({'styles':'', 'sld_body':_sld });
```

does not work. This is the basic for query and I a struck.

Comment: I found a solution in ol3 dev group by Arnd Wippermann. It worked which is " as you have to use the name of your wms layer you want to style: <Name>ktmemis:rna_disaster_incident</Name> instead of <Name>Simple Point</Name>" please refer to the updated fiddle
 
jsfiddle.net/shumanbaral/x6qwyuvk/8/

 which works like a charm